# Does there exist a nearly immaculate group not of the form $C_{2^n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Define a nearly immaculate group as a finite group $G$, such, that the sum of the orders of all its normal subgroups is $2|G| - 1$. It is quite obvious to see, that all groups of the form $C_{2^n}$ are nearly immaculate. But are there any not of the type?

One can see, that a cyclic group $C_n$ is nearly immaculate iff $n$ is almost perfect. Whether all almost perfect numbers are of the form $2^n$ or not, is an open problem. But, what’s about non-cyclic nearly immaculate groups? Do they exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not  have a full answer, but I can show that such an example cannot be a $p$-group. It seems challanging to generalize this to nilpotent groups.

Claim: among the (finite) $p$-groups, $G\cong C_{2^n}$ are the only examples.

Proof: If $p\neq 2$, then the order of every nontrivial normal subgroup is divisible by $p$, so the sum of orders is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. 
Hence, it cannot be $2|G|-1$. 
If $p=2$ and $G=2^n$, then there exists a normal subgroup in $G$ of order $2^k$ for every $0\leq k\leq n$. 
As the sum of these orders is $2^{n+1}-1= 2|G|-1$, there must be exactly one of each. 
In particular, there is a unique maximal normal subgroup $M\triangleleft G$, and thus any element $g\notin M$ generates $G$.